# How to parse upload and download speed with ifstat and printf?

Tags: bash, awk

In bash I'm trying to display rounded (no decimals) download and upload speed in readable format i.e something like that:

> Download 16KB Upload 200KB

I got this but its not quite working:

```
ifstat 1 1 | tail -n 1 | awk ' {printf "Down=%.0f\n", $1 } printf {"KB"} {printf " Up=%.0f", $2}' {printf "KB"}
```

Comment: Try `{printf "Down=%.0fKB Up=%.0fKB", $1, $2}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `awk` for this:

```bash
printf "Download %.0f KB/s Upload %.0f KB/s\n" $(ifstat 1 1 | tail -n1)
```

Comment: (1) This relies on the shell splitting the unquoted command substitution. The splitting depends on the value of `$IFS`. With non-default `$IFS` the command may fail. (2) In my Kubuntu `ifstat` prints numbers using dot (`.`) as the decimal separator, regardless of locale. Depending on the locale and the implementation of `printf` one uses (so in practice on the shell), `printf` may or may not accept such numbers as numbers.

Comment: this also prints out up down from other interfaces which is not quite I needed. However I simply added another head at the end: printf "Download %.0f KB/s\nUpload %.0f KB/s\n" $(ifstat 1 1 |tail -n 1) | head -n 2

Comment: @okoolo Cannot you use `ifstat -i`?